# link kibana search query to a certain time

Tags: kibana

I have a search saved in Kibana called `foo` which searches for the keyword `bar` in the **time range 1 week**.

From this search, I made a metric visualization `foobar` and have it in my dashboard. 
When I change the time frame of my dashboard to say, 1 year, `foobar` also gets updated to represent the data in the new time frame. I want to have `foobar` stick to representing 1 week's data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, because if each visualisation has its own time range, the dashboard will be meaning less.
The meaning of dashboard is, group of visualisations with the same search query and filter.